# 86% achieved in testclass how to achieve remaining 14% inside IF Statement code not working

Tags: unit-test

**Class**

```
public class Addcontrol {

    Public String msgbox {get;set;}   
    Public String Name {get;set;}
    Public Integer expense_number  {get;set;}
    public list<Expense__C> conlist {get;set;}
    Public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}
    Public Expense__c Expense{get;set;}
    Expense__c Expense1 = new Expense__c();
    Expense__c Expense2 = new Expense__c();

    public PageReference saved() {
    integer flag=0;
        for(Expense__C con :conlist ){
             if(con.name==NULL && con.expense_number__c==NULL  || con.name==''  ){
                flag=1;
    }
       }
   /*from here the test class code is not working*/
    if(flag==0){

            insert conlist;
            conlist=new list<Expense__C>();
            msgbox='Records saved Successfully !!!';
            Expense__c Expense1 = new Expense__c();
            conlist.add(Expense1);

    }
    else{
     ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.info,'Blank Rows are not Allowed'));
    }
    return null;
}

    public  Addcontrol (){
    conlist=new list<Expense__C>();
    conlist.add(Expense1);
   }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class AddcontrolTestclass{

    static testMethod void AddControlTestmethod() {
    Addcontrol Addctrlobj= new Addcontrol();

    apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('rowIndex','0');
        Addctrlobj.saved();
        Expense__c Exp_obj = new Expense__c(name='Kishore',expense_number__c=132); 
        list <Expense__c> Exp_list= new list <Expense__c>();
        Exp_list.add(Exp_obj);
        insert Exp_list;


    }
}
```

Comment: What scenarios in your test class will result in flag == 0?

Comment: here there a 2 text fields whenever the save button is clicked it'll validate the code and if they are not null then save the record

Answer (score 1):

You call

> Addctrlobj.saved();

before

> Expense__c Exp_obj = new Expense__c(name='Kishore',expense_number__c=132);

This means that

> con.name==NULL && con.expense_number__c==NULL

results in true and flag is set to 1. This is why the code inside your if-statement is never tested. You will have to write a test where you create the Expense__c object before running the saved() method.

Another point: You never use the System.assert() or System.assertEquals() methods. This means that you never actually test your code. Have a look at the documentation for more information about testing:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_testing.htm